# Query SQL hour to minute

Tags: sql, time

I have this column `Break` in integer format.

The values are:

- 100 = 1h
- 130 = 1h and 30 minutes

I need to extract the minutes from this column:

- 100 = 1h = 60 minutes
- 130 = 1h and 30m =  90 minutes

I tried with this SQL, but it doesn't work:

```
select  
    convert(int, datediff(minute, 0, convert(varchar(8), dateadd(minute, TSH1."Break", ''), 114) )) 
from TSH1
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please provide sample input and expected outcome.

Comment: the actual column is break (int values)

example

Break     New result
100   |   60
130   |   90
200   |   120 
210   |   130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will produce the output you want

```
select  
    (((CAST(TSH1."Break" AS INT) / 100) * 60) + (CAST(TSH1."Break" AS INT) % 100)) As col
from TSH1
```